# Understanding RandomGen#next

Tags: haskell

Looking at [RandomGen#next](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.1/docs/System-Random.html#t%3aStdGen), the docs say:

```
next :: g -> (Int, g)

The next operation returns an Int that is uniformly distributed in the range 
returned by genRange (including both end points), and a new generator.
```

Playing with it in REPL, I would've expected `x next` to have printed out the same number.

```
ghci> let x = getStdRandom
ghci> x next
169285648
ghci> x next
473378030
ghci> x next
896978399
```

Why isn't `x next` referentially transparent, i.e. calling `x next` always returns the same output?

Comment: it is! You're in `IO ()` though.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the definition of `getStdRandom`:

```
getStdRandom :: (StdGen -> (a,StdGen)) -> IO a
getStdRandom f = atomicModifyIORef theStdGen (swap . f)
```

In other words, it does something like this (but atomically):

```
getStdRandom f = do
    gen <- getStdGen
    let (result, gen') = f gen
    setStdGen gen'
    return result
```

So it gets the random number generator, runs your function, then puts that new random number generator in place. When you run `getStdRandom next` a few times, it’ll retrieve the random number generator at the start, thread the random number generators such that each next one receives the new random number generator from the last one. That means that each invocation of `next` receives a different random number generator.

But how can this happen if `getStdRandom next` is of type `Int`? Trick is, it’s not. It’s of type `IO Int`, which GHCi will automatically execute and display the result value of as if it were an `Int` in the first place.

If you want to get a random number generator from the environment and use it several times, you should get it once (rather than getting a function which threads the RNG state through your function and returns another `IO`) and then use that:

```
ghci> x <- getStdGen
ghci> next x
(803259519,803300211 40692)
ghci> next x
(803259519,803300211 40692)
ghci> next x
(803259519,803300211 40692)
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on here you need to examine the type signature of `getStdRandom`.

```
> :t getStdRandom
getStdRandom :: (StdGen -> (a, StdGen)) -> IO a
```

getStdRandom returns `IO a` so returning the same value with the same inputs is  not necessarily on the table.

The documentation for [getStdRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.1/docs/System-Random.html#v%3agetStdRandom) stating that it "get a value from the current global random generator, and updates the global generator with the new generator".  So the global generator is being updated with every call.